# Sumarize column using TAggregatefield with distinct index of Firedac query in Delphi

Tags: delphi, firedac, aggregates

I'm using Delphi XE5 and i have a firedac query (FDQuery) with three columns: (Account, value, Vendor) and i need sum the value field per Account on TAggregateField. The same account can have many vendors.

```
Account | Value | Vendor
1       | 100.00| Joe
1       | 100.00| Max
2       | 500.00| Wily
```

**So, can i sum the value field getting distinct Account (total value: 600,00 not 700,00) without sort or filter the FDQuery?**

What have I tried?
In design mode, I created an aggregate field named "AggAccountsTotal" with the following properties:

```
Expression = 'sum(value)';
Active = True
```

...and created a TFDIndex with the following properties:

```
Distinct = True
Name = idxsumAccountvalue
Fields = Account
Active = True
```

However, when you enable FDQuery aggregate fields and try to set the `IndexName` property in the aggregate field (not FDQUEry), it does not appear in the combobox. If you manually assign the name, the following error occurs:

> Access violation at address 1419398F in module 'FireDACCommon190.bpl'.
>   Read of address 00000020.

[image: This is the error screenshot]

Is this behavior expected and am I doing something wrong or is delphi / Firedac Bug?

Comment: I find it easier in such situations to use a separate query which calculates the distinct total.